# Duplicate rows after multiple SQL Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, ax

Im getting many duplicate rows from this query. Is there something wrong with my left joins? I have tried inners joins also but they dont help at all. I think the problem is something that if one left join is true then it adds a row to the results

```
SELECT DP.FirstName, DP.LastName, DECA.Email, UI.Id, ET.EmplId,
HPPTR.OrganizationUnitId, A.CountryRegionId, ET.EmplIdentNumber,
ET.JobId_INN, HPPTR.Description, ET.HRMResponsible_INN, A.Street, A.ZipCode,
A.City, HPER.ValidFromDateTime, HCJF.INN_JobAgreementType,
HPJTR.INN_EmpJobType, HPPTR.hrmemploymentfactor

FROM DirPartyTable AS DP

LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYECOMMUNICATIONRELA2608 AS DPECR ON DP.PartyId = DPECR.PartyId
LEFT JOIN DirECommunicationAddress AS DECA ON DPECR.ValuesRecId = DECA.RecId

LEFT JOIN EmplTable AS ET ON DP.PartyId = ET.PartyId
LEFT JOIN SYSCOMPANYUSERINFO AS SCUI ON ET.EmplId = SCUI.EmplId
LEFT JOIN USERINFO AS UI ON SCUI.UserId = UI.Id

LEFT JOIN HRPPARTYPOSITIONTABLERELAT2226 AS HPPTR ON ET.EmplId = HPPTR.Reference
LEFT JOIN HRPPartyJobTableRelationship AS HPJTR ON HPPTR.JobId = HPJTR.Jobid
LEFT JOIN HRMCompJobFunction AS HCJF ON HPJTR.HrmCompJobFunctionId = HCJF.JobFunctionId

LEFT JOIN Address AS A ON ET.RecId = A.AddrRecId

LEFT JOIN HRMPARTYEMPLOYEERELATIONSHIP AS HPER ON ET.EmplId = HPER.EmplId

WHERE DP.DataAreaId != 'cvc'
AND DECA.ECommunicationTypeId = 'email'
AND A.addrtableid='256'
AND UI.NETWORKALIAS IS NOT NULL
AND A.DataAreaId = DP.DataAreaId
AND SCUI.DataAreaId = DP.DataAreaId
AND ET.DataAreaId = DP.DataAreaId

ORDER BY ET.EmplId
```

Here is schema

```
FirstName   LastName    Email   Id  EmplId  OrganizationUnitId  CountryRegionId EmplIdentNumber CountryRegionId Description     Street  ZipCode City    ValidFromDateTime   INN_JobAgreementType    INN_EmpJobType  hrmemploymentfactor
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234523   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234524   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234525   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234526   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234527   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234528   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234529   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234530   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234531   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234532   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-02-16 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234533   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234534   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234535   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234536   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234537   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234538   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234539   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234540   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234541   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234542   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2009-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234543   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234544   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234545   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234546   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234547   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234548   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234549   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234550   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234551   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234552   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234553   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234554   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234555   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234556   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234557   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234558   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234559   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234560   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234561   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234562   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234563   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234564   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234565   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234566   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234567   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org1    FI  131564-234568   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org2    FI  131564-234569   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org3    FI  131564-234570   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org4    FI  131564-234571   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        1.000000000000
John    Head    john.head@example.com   johnh   headjh  org5    FI  131564-234572   CHZ IT GUY      rockstreet  534523  Bigplace    2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 NULL        0.000000000000
```

Comment: care to share your table schema?

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider whether the column on the 'right' is unique or not.

Eg: in

```
FROM DirPartyTable AS DP
LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYECOMMUNICATIONRELA2608 AS DPECR ON DP.PartyId = DPECR.PartyId
```

Is `DPECR.PartyID` unique? If it's not, then every row in DP that maps to multiple rows in DPECR will appear multiple times.

...and this continues for all your other joins. Syntax-wise, they're fine, but you need to ask yourself about the uniqueness.

To figure out what's going on, try doing `SELECT 1` instead of your field list, and starting with the just first table, see how many rows are returned. Then try the first two or three tables, until you can figure out which joins make the number of rows returned grow. Those ones are your problems and warrant further investigation into your table design.

Comment: Do you mean that is matter in which order I put the tables after ON-word? Example it is different if I write DP.PartyId = DPECR.PartyId or DPECR.PartyId = DP.PartyId

Comment: No. That won't affect it. If multiple rows are matches between the columns you've joined on, you'll get every combination.

Comment: Okay thx and what you mean by SELECT 1? Can you give me example how I start to investigate the joins?

Comment: If you don't change your SELECT clause you'll get errors. You could use `COUNT(*)` too. Start with: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DirPartyTable AS DP` and then try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DirPartyTable AS DP LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYECOMMUNICATIONRELA2608 AS DPECR ON DP.PartyId = DPECR.PartyId` and so on, looking for when the value increases.